# How to get data from a DB(MySQL) and draw real-time graphs from a highcharts

Tags: php, html

I'm going to use the real-time temperature values stored in MariaDB server to show real-time graphs on the web.
(Temperature values continue to accumulate in real time once every 5 seconds.)

Through a lot of trial and error, I decided that Highcharts.js would be the best tool for drawing graphs.

https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

The link above is the demo source I used.

What I've been trying to do in the most 
I've been putting a lot of things into the bar y.

I tried various things in the data.push of series.

(I'm a beginner on coding......)

I didn't know what I typed wrong, so I entered everything. I'm sorry.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>


  <script>

 Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {

       var series = this.series[0];



setInterval(function() {


                 $(document).ready(function() {
                 var url = "https://---include json---.php";
                $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                    var val= json;
                    var temp1=(json['temp'][(Object.keys(json['temp']).length)-1]['temp1']); 
                    console.log(json['temp'][(Object.keys(json['temp']).length)-1]['temp1']);
                    })});


          var x = (new Date()).getTime() // current time
          var y = temp1;

           Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);//연속
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },



  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      count: 1,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '1M'
    }, {
      count: 5,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '5M'
    }, {
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }],
    inputEnabled: false,
    selected: 0
  },

  title: {
    text: 'TEST test'
  },

  exporting: {
    enabled: true
  },
  credits:{
    enabled:false
  },


  series: [
  {
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function() {     



      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        y;      
      for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {

          data.push([
          //time + i * 1000, 
          //Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }]


});


  </script>
```

The following php code is the php code for json data.

```
<?php

//Creating Array for JSON response
$response = array();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "!";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp2 order by id asc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
$response["temp"] = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$temp = array();      
$temp["temp1"] = $row["temp1"];
array_push($response["temp"], $temp);
          }
      echo json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results",JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

The above code values are output as shown below.

```
{"temp":[
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.82},
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},  
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":18.05},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.82},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.82},{"temp1":18.05},{"temp1":17.93},{"temp1":17.93},
  {"temp1":17.93}
]}
```

**If you run the code, the graph won't appear on the screen.**

I don't know how to print out json's value on the graph.

I translated it using Google translation because I am not good at English. I would like to thank you all for your reply.

Comment: Hello Haduk and welcome to SO. Could you open up the Web Developer Tools (Press F12), reload the page and check if you see any errors in the "Console" tab? Highcharts will most likely give you some feedback if things went wrong. Also please add `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` before using `print json_encode(...);` otherwise the AJAX call will interpret the result not as proper JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Add a content type to the header:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chart.js library. Simple and powerful
https://www.chartjs.org

Here are some example how to use:
https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Wellcome to SO :)

I think you have the wrong Dataformat for your Data. You have a Array of Objects

```
[{"temp1":17.93},....]
```

But the example say:

```
data.push([
    time + i * 1000,
    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
]);
```

An Array of Array. Try this:

```
<?php
    //Creating Array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "!";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM temp2 order by id asc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $response["temp"] = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $response["temp"][] = array("temp1", $row["temp1"]);  // <-- change this line
        }
        echo json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("0 results",JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```